# How do I convert yyyy DDD HH:mm:ss into a ZonedDateTime>

Tags: java, date, javafx, time, zoneddatetime

I've been working on some code for a while and I can't seem to figure this bit out. I've got 5 spinners for each field of year, day of year, hour, minute, and second. My goal is to take those 5 parameters and use them to create a ZonedDateTime that can be sent out, but I have no clue where to go with this because of the difficulties of using the day of year format (which I can't change).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
int yr = ...;
int dayOfYear = ... ;
int hour = ... ;
int minute = ... ;
int second =  ... ;
```

(which you can get from your spinners)

You can do

```
LocalDate date = Year.of(yr).atDay(dayOfYear);
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(hour, minute, second);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(date, time, ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Answer (score 4):

It’s not difficult when you know how:

```
    ZonedDateTime dt = LocalDate.ofYearDay(2017, 86)
            .atTime(16, 28, 55)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

On my computer this gives `2017-03-27T16:28:55+02:00[Europe/Oslo]`.

Please substitute your five numbers into the places where I have given int literals. You may also want to substitute another time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Just use ZonedDateTime `parse` method like that:

```
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.parse(
     "2017 101 12:01:01",                                        
     DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy DDD HH:mm:ss").withZone(
          ZoneId.systemDefault()
     )
);
```

Note that this will return a "date time" in the "system default" timezone (as it is not a part of your input pattern).

Also, the input value for the "day of the year", must be left-padded with zeroes, e.g.

```
31 => 031
```

You can do it (for example), like that:

```
String.format("%04d %03d %02d:%02d:%02d",year,doy,hour,minute,second)
```

(where year,doy,... are integer values from your spinners)

Comment: It seems a bit much to take 5 individual values, concatenate them into a string, and then parse the string back out, though...

Answer (score 0):

Generate a **LocalDateTime** from the values you got from spinners and get a **ZonedDateTime** object

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy  hh:mm:ss.SSS a");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JULY, 17, 19, 30, 15, 333);     

ZonedDateTime zonedDateT = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));

System.out.println(zonedDateT.format(formatter));
```

Comment: The asker asked to have the 5 numbers converted to a `ZonedDateTime`. Aren’t you doing the opposite?

Comment: nop, those 5 valeus are supposed to be placed in line 2

Comment: But the OP doesn't have month and day of month.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have the day n month/month so this method doesn't fit the description, but thanks anyway!